# AlarmManager to start Service not working

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I have an `IntentService` class and I want to user an Alarm to make the service perform a certain task every X hours.

I retrieve the alarm and set it but the service performs its task every 2 seconds instead of every X hours; it's never stopping: the `BroadcastReceiver` is always firing the `Intent`.

This is the code:

```
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        int alarmType = AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP;
        username = intent.getStringExtra("username");
        //android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
        alarms = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        serviceToStart = intent.getStringExtra("serviceToStart");

        if (serviceToStart.equals("calls")) {
            String CALLS_ALARM_ACTION = "ACTION_CALLS_LOGGING";
            Intent callsIntentToFire = new Intent(CALLS_ALARM_ACTION);
            callsIntentToFire.putExtra("serviceToStart", serviceToStart);
            callsAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, callsIntentToFire, 0);
            callsUpdatefrequency = toLong(Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString(Preferences.CALLS_FREQUENCY_PREF, "0")));
            long callsTimeToUpdate = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + callsUpdatefrequency;
            alarms.setRepeating(alarmType, callsTimeToUpdate, callsUpdatefrequency, callsAlarmIntent);
            dumpCallsLog();
```

The last method (dumpCallsLog()) is the method that updates a remote DB.
Is there anything I'm missing or that it's incorrect in the code?

This is my `BroadcastReceiver` code:

```
public class LoggingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String ACTION_CALLS_LOGGING = "ACTION_CALLS_LOGGING";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, LoggingService.class);
        String action = intent.getStringExtra("serviceToStart");
        startIntent.putExtra("serviceToStart", action);
        context.startService(startIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `callsUpdatefrequency` expressed in milliseconds? And why is the default value `0`?

Comment: @CommonsWare well `callsUpdateFrequency` is now, using debug values 50000 (which should be milliseconds?) and the default value is my bad, as it should be one hour expressed in millisecs. Nevertheless, that was the my base code; the rest of the time I'm experimenting trying to come up with the solution for the problem (not found yet by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done! My bad:

```
String CALLS_ALARM_ACTION = "ACTION_CALLS_LOGGING";
                    Intent callsIntentToFire = new Intent(CALLS_ALARM_ACTION);

                    callsIntentToFire.putExtra("serviceToStart", "dumpCalls");
                    callsIntentToFire.putExtra("username", username);

                    callsAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, callsIntentToFire, 0);

                    callsTriggerAlarmTime = AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP;

                    long callsAlarmInterval = 30000L;
                    // toLong(Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString(Preferences.CALLS_FREQUENCY_PREF,
                    // "86400000")));

                    alarms.setRepeating(alarmType, callsTriggerAlarmTime,
                            callsAlarmInterval, callsAlarmIntent);
```